# Beatrix's board and holes

Tags: contest-math, recreational-mathematics, discrete-optimization, tiling

This is the last question from [UKMT's JMC 2016](https://www.ukmt.org.uk/sites/default/files/ukmt/junior-mathematical-challenge/jmc-2016-extended.pdf):

> Beatrix places dominoes on a 5 × 5 board, either horizontally or
> vertically, so that each domino covers two small squares. She stops
> when she cannot place another domino, as in the example shown in the
> diagram.
>
> When Beatrix stops, what is the largest possible number of squares
> that may be still uncovered?

The answer is 7, as shown below:

[image]

Is there a general answer for $n\times n$ board? For example, is there a way to count, covering a $19\times 19$ board, how many holes Beatrix can leave on the board?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is equivalent to computing the [independent domination number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominating_set#Independent_domination) of a graph with a node for each of the $2n(n-1)$ dominoes and an edge for each pair of dominoes that share a cell.
See [Minimum number of dominoes on an $n \times n$ chessboard to prevent placement of another domino.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3191721/minimum-number-of-dominoes-on-an-n-times-n-chessboard-to-prevent-placement-of), which links to https://oeis.org/A280984.

For $n=5$, number the horizontal dominoes $1$ through $20$ (top to bottom and then left to right), and number the vertical dominoes $21$ through $40$ (left to right and then top to bottom).  Then dominoes $1$ and $6$ share cell $(1,2)$, and the full set of edges is
$$\{(1,6),(1,21),(1,22),(2,7),(2,21),(2,22),(2,26),(2,27),(3,8),(3,26),(3,27),(3,31),(3,32),(4,9),(4,31),(4,32),(4,36),(4,37),(5,10),(5,36),(5,37),(6,11),(6,22),(6,23),(7,12),(7,22),(7,23),(7,27),(7,28),(8,13),(8,27),(8,28),(8,32),(8,33),(9,14),(9,32),(9,33),(9,37),(9,38),(10,15),(10,37),(10,38),(11,16),(11,23),(11,24),(12,17),(12,23),(12,24),(12,28),(12,29),(13,18),(13,28),(13,29),(13,33),(13,34),(14,19),(14,33),(14,34),(14,38),(14,39),(15,20),(15,38),(15,39),(16,24),(16,25),(17,24),(17,25),(17,29),(17,30),(18,29),(18,30),(18,34),(18,35),(19,34),(19,35),(19,39),(19,40),(20,39),(20,40),(21,26),(22,27),(23,28),(24,29),(25,30),(26,31),(27,32),(28,33),(29,34),(30,35),(31,36),(32,37),(33,38),(34,39),(35,40)\}$$

The independent domination number for $n=5$ is $9$, which implies that the largest remaining number of uncovered cells is $5^2-2\cdot9=7$, as you found.  For $n=19$, the independent domination number is $122$, which implies that the largest remaining number of uncovered cells is $19^2-2\cdot122=117$.

Comment: I don't quite get the line *a graph with a node for each of the 2n(n−1) dominoes and an edge for each pair of dominoes that share a cell*. could you show as an example, for a $5\times 5$ board, what is the corresponding graph?

Comment: @athos I updated my answer with the graph for $n=5$.